# How do I sum the values in a Reactor Flux stream?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Suppose I have a repository with a `findAll()` method that returns an `Iterable` of `State`, where `State` is a class representing a US state that has two fields (with getter/setters): `name`, and `population`.

I want to get the sum of the population fields for all `State`s in my Flux. 
 I create a Flux from an Iterable, as follows:

```
Flux f = Flux.fromIterable(stateRepo.findAll());
```

I've got my Flux, but I don't know of a good way to sum up its values. 
 I've tried something like

```
int total = 0;
f.map(s -> s.getPopulation()).subscribe(p -> total += v);
return total;
```

However, the compiler says that total "should be final or effectively final".  Adding `final` obviously won't work, because I'm trying to add to it.

How do I go about summing (or any other aggregate function) on a Flux?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use **reduce** method:

```
@GetMapping("/populations")
    public Mono<Integer> getPopulation() {
        return Flux.fromIterable(stateRepo.findAll())
                .map(s -> s.getPopulation())
                .reduce(0, (x1, x2) -> x1 + x2)
                .map(this::someFunction); //you can also handle the sum, if you wish
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I went more or less with this answer.  I discovered that if the `Iterable` I create the Flux from happens to be empty then I get a NullPointerException.  I worked around this by using `.reduce(0, (x1, x2) -> x1 + x2)`, where the 0 arg is the initial value for the aggregate.  Also, using `block()` instead of `subscribe()` causes the aggregate value to be returned.

Comment: Great. I wold suggest to avoid using block method in production as you block yourself an wait for result. 
If you use Spring Boot and need to process that sum of populations than do it in extra map method and return the Mono(it is a Mono after reducing) as a controller result.

Example:

@GetMapping("/populations")
    public Mono<Integer> getPopulation() {
        Flux.fromIterable(stateRepo.findAll())
                .map(s -> s.getPopulation())
                .reduce(0, (x1, x2) -> x1 + x2)
                .map(this::someFunction); // here you can handle the sum
    }

Comment: note this is the more generified method that would work with any type. can you give details about the NPE? that sounds strange to me.

Comment: `.reduce(0, (x1, x2) -> x1 + x2)`
can be replaced with
`.reduce(0, Integer:sum)`

Answer (score 5):

You can import reactor extra package from maven

`io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra`

and then use `MathFlux.sumInt(integresFlux)`
docs: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#extra-math

Comment: note this is the more specialized method that would work with `Numbers`